# Migrate search layout of standard objects

Tags: deployment, metadata-api

I have added some columns to the lookup and search result layouts of standard objects like account and user. Is there any way to migrate only the search layout part of these objects. I do not want to migrate the whole objects since there might be unwanted changes in the current configuration too.
On a general note, is it always possible to migrate only specific changes of objects - custom or standard. Kindly forgive my inexperience in the matter if the question seems redundant. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salesforce often encodes lots and lots of information in a single object, or single XML file in the Metadata API. Normally, this means that you have to manually edit the XML. Your workflow then looks like:

1. Use the Force.com Migration Tool (ANT) to download all the `CustomObject`'s from source
2. Use the Force.com Migration Tool (ANT) to download all the `CustomObject`'s from target
3. Manually copy the `<SearchLayout>` section of each `.object` xml file to include the changes you have made
4. Use the Force.com Migration Tool (ANT) to upload the modified `.object` xml files to the target

It may be the product I work on, [Gearset](https://gearset.com), might be of help here. We normally split up objects into small chunks, but we we don't with Search Layout unfortunately. That said, we do break enough other things out of objects like new custom fields, or edits to standard fields, that you might be able to get away with it.

I highly recommend you use our totally free, no-commitment, [30-day trial](https://gearset.com) to run a comparison and see if Gearset will solve your issue. Let me know if it doesn't so we can make the product better!

[image: Search Layouts in Gearset]

[image: Custom Field being separate in Gearset]

Comment: Hopefully it is useful for you @Stygon, but it Gearset doesn't work or your trial runs out then that manual xml editing process will solve your problem too. Let me know if you use Gearset and it doesn't solve your issue though! (kevin@gearset.com)